# imagemagick remove clusters of pixels

Tags: imagemagick

Original image:

[image]

I want to isolate and remove (i.e. turn to white) small clumps of pixels with large amounts of white space around them. Examples of pixel areas I would like to turn to white:

[image]

The goal is to get larger unbroken areas of white space. Example of the final result:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what to think of examples of pixels that should be "turned to white" as you say - you could elaborate more on the question, because it's not really obvious what are you trying to accomplish here. My guess is that you are looking after median filter, if so, here is an example: `convert gmyjf.jpg -median 5 gmyjf2.jpg` (where `gmyjf.jpg` would be the path to the original file)

Comment: convert gmyjf.jpg -median 5 gmyjf2.jpg has solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Small clusters of pixels can be filtered out using the median filter with imagemagick like this:

```
convert gmyjf.jpg -median 5 gmyjf2.jpg
```

(where gmyjf.jpg would be the path to the original file)